# Azure Functions host.json settings per function or global?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Do the settings in host.json apply to each function individually, or apply to all of the functions as a whole?

For example, I've two functions in the same Project that both get messages from Azure ServiceBus Queues.

If I set maxConcurrentCalls to 10 in host.json, does that mean that as a whole only 10 concurrent calls to ServiceBus will be made, or that it is 10 *per function*, so there will be 20 concurrent calls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`host.json` file is shared for all functions of a FunctionApp. That's to say that `maxConcurrentCalls` value will apply to all functions of the app, as any other setting will.

The effect of `maxConcurrentCalls` will be independent for each function. In your example, each function will have up to 10 messages processed concurrently. If you set it to 1, there will be 1 thread working per function.

Note that `maxConcurrentCalls` applies per instance. If you have multiple instances running, the max concurrency increases proportionally.

Comment: While this appears to be correct, it really kind of baffles me. Certain settings would be very helpful if you could override them at a per-function level. For example, `queues` -> `batchSize`. Right now, it looks like you need to have a separate function app to accomplish the same thing. I posted an issue on Github to see if it is possible to change this (if not now, hopefully in the future): https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5972

Comment: Yep, you could set a singleton attribute on the function maybe if you just want one, but it should be configurable per function. In my case it's more than 1.