# Per function hosts.json settings instead of global

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I wanted to set a non-global maxDequeueCount for Azure Storage Queues in my Azure Functions.

For example, in function_a.py, I'd like to have a maxDequeueCount of 5, but in function_b.py, I'd like it to be 1.

From what I understand this is not possible in many sections of Azure Functions, and I was wondering if there is a better workaround than just creating a separate function app.

The only question I found on this topic is this one from three years ago, and I find the conclusion unsatisfactory: [Azure Functions host.json settings per function or global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431298/azure-functions-host-json-settings-per-function-or-global)

Answer (score 2):

Only two possibilities are:

1. Create separate Function Apps for each Function and provide a different `host.json`.
2. Don't use trigger/input binding, instead use a timer-trigger and do your own polling using Storage Q API ([Java](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-storage-queue/12.8.0/com/azure/storage/queue/QueueClient.html#receiveMessages-java.lang.Integer-java.time.Duration-java.time.Duration-com.azure.core.util.Context-), [Python](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-queue/12.1.5/index.html#receiving-messages)). You of course implement all the logic related to acknowledging/receipts/batching/timeouts/retries/... etc.

PS: I agree, it's not nice that settings that should be controllable per Function are inside `host.json`